# Drive a DC motor with a WS2811 chip

Tags: arduino, transistors, motor, robotics, ws2811

I'm building a robot that needs a lot of small hobby motors (or similar) to operate in sync. I was looking for ways to have as many of them controlled by a single source of logic as I am not sure I can sync multiple sources well enough. The motors will need to spin at variable speeds, individually from each other.

I was looking for a way to get the data up to the motors and I remembered about [WS2811](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) chips. Could I possibly use them (without LEDS) as a way to transmit data to daisy-chained motors? Looking at the datasheet for the chip it seems it should be able to support 5 V outputs. I could also maybe put a transistor in there to avoid the full power going through the chip.

At the same time, thinking about it, it sounds like a crazy idea and I do not know enough about motors to figure out if it would be possible. I could really use help understanding where I'm wrong and how can I learn more, and maybe what a proper solution would be.

Comment: Not sure if connecting them directly would be a good idea since we don't know if WS2811 would sustain the inrush currents of motors. There are however applications where WS28XX ICs are used to drive FETs/Transistors as open drain LED drivers, so you could work based on that. Then I would be worried about the noise from the motors interfering with the "Data" signal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll try to look into the transistor solution you mentioned. Would you mind elaborating on the noise from the motor? Thanks!

Comment: @ColumnB can you provide more details about how many motors you are using? What do you mean by 'daisy chained' motors? What exactly is it that you're trying to do? This smells like an 'XY problem' situation to me (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)

Answer (score 0):

If your motors are PMDC brushed ones you need pwm-output driver for each motor. Since WS2811 chips have constant current output you cannot use it for speed adjustment.

You may use PCA9685 (e.g.: https://www.adafruit.com/product/815) with output MOSFET stages. Because it's top pwm frequency is 1.6kHz you may hear switching noise. You can try to find similar PWM IO expanders with higher PWM frequency preferably higher than 20kHz.

Comment: Similar project https://hackaday.io/project/27112-haptivision

Comment: This is super helpful thanks! Could you explain "chips have constant current output"? Reading the datasheet for the chip seems to say the RGB outputs are PWM, unless you are referring to something different... The PCA9685 looks absolutely awesome, thank you so much for the tip! The noise isn't really a problem as long as it doesn't affect reliability I think. I'll look into additional PWM extenders. Thank you once again!

Comment: WS2811 type LED drivers have constant current open-drain outputs for keeping current constant through LEDs in order to keep LED's luminosity constant and equivalent in-between